# jenkins pod cannot find its own local programs

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have Jenkins using kubernetes for creating ephemeral pods.
Recently I wanted to build `.net` solution so I built a custom image to inject `.netSDK` to my pod.

```
FROM jenkins/inbound-agent
USER root
RUN apt-get update;
RUN apt install wget
RUN wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb 
RUN dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
RUN rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-5.0
USER jenkins
```

I just followed the steps from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-debian).

After That I made sure that Jenkins will pull this new image when claiming a pod.
However when I run this pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    parameters{
        string(name: 'url', description: 'repository url')
        string(name: 'branch', description: 'branch name')
        string(name: 'agent', description: 'agent name')
    }

  agent { label "${params.agent}" }

  stages {

    stage('test') {
      steps {
            sh 'dotnet --info'
        }
    }
    ...
    }   
  }
}
```

it throws an error message: `dotnet: not found`

```
/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/pipeline_DotnetBuild@tmp/durable-eb21aaa2/script.sh: 1: 

/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/pipeline_DotnetBuild@tmp/durable-eb21aaa2/script.sh: dotnet: not found
```

So I did connect to the pod in bash mode to see what’s going on.
And I could execute:
`jenkins@pod-f9xm0:~$ dotnet`

```
Usage: dotnet [options]
Usage: dotnet [path-to-application]
…
```

The dotnet file is located in `usr/bin/dotnet` as well inside the pod.

So I am wondering what is going on here? I clearly misunderstand some concepts.

Thank you for your help and explanations!

Comment: to make a binary accessible system-wide to multiple users, it should be placed by an administrator into /usr/local/bin

Comment: weird, it doesn't really match what you said: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/usr-bin-vs-usr-local-bin-on-linux Or did I miss read

Comment: I did add this command in the dockerfile : RUN cp /usr/bin/dotnet /usr/local/bin but still same behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After replicating your issue as closely as possible, I was getting similar results.

Starting dotnet from script with `sh 'dotnet --info'` is throwing an error

```text
jenkins@157d7dfc5949:~$ cat test.sh 
sh 'dotnet --info'
```

```text
jenkins@157d7dfc5949:~$ ./test.sh 
sh: 0: Can't open dotnet --info
```

Replacing `sh 'dotnet --info'` with `/bin/bash -c dotnet --info` fixed the issue.

```text
jenkins@157d7dfc5949:~$ cat test.sh 
/bin/bash -c dotnet --info
```

```text
jenkins@157d7dfc5949:~$ ./test.sh 

Usage: dotnet [options]
Usage: dotnet [path-to-application]

Options:
  -h|--help         Display help.
  --info            Display .NET information.
  --list-sdks       Display the installed SDKs.
  --list-runtimes   Display the installed runtimes.

path-to-application:
  The path to an application .dll file to execute.
```